# Angular 6 - Error on production build with Boolean and [ngClass]

Tags: angular, angular-aot

I have this variable to my component

```
showMenu: Boolean = false;
```

and I'm using this on my html file

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{true: 'show'}[showMenu === true]">
```

and I'm getting this error

```
ERROR in src/app/core/layouts/main/main-layout.component.html(14,54): : Type 'boolean' cannot be used as an index type.
```

What does this mean? I'm getting this only on

```
ng build --prod
```

"ng serve" works perfect

Comment: what are you trying to get with this `{true: 'show'}[showMenu === true]`? or what you think you should get?

Comment: Try `[ngClass]="{ 'show': showMenu }"`.

Comment: Or this other syntax: `[class.show]="showMenu"`.